# Compare new Vector2 position with previous Vector2 position

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to place different objects in the game area like a grid, but I have some problem with my method that creates this objects and there positions. I'm trying to store each new positions in a List and then compare each new positions with the ones in the List before it's OK to use it as a new position in the grid of the game area. I only want to use each random position once. Help is preciated! Thanks!

Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

```
public void AddItemsToGameArea(ContentManager content)
{
    foreach (string buildingPart in contentHouseOne)
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = NewRandomPosition;
        if (!checkPreviousPositions)
        {
            listHouseParts.Add(new HousePart(content, buildingPart, newPosition));
            listUsedPosition.Add(newPosition);
            checkPreviousPositions = true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listUsedPosition.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Check?? 
            }

        }
    }
}

public Vector2 NewRandomPosition
{
    get
    {
        return new Vector2(gridPixels * Game1.random.Next(1, 8), gridPixels * Game1.random.Next(1, 8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should think about using an array of bool's to handle the grid:

```
bool occupiedPositions[columns, rows];
```

So, when you occupy a grid cell you do this:

```
occupiedPositons[i, j] = true;
```

You could also generate a list with the available positions of the grid and take positions randomly from it and eliminate elements when you do:

```
List<Vector2> emptyCells;

// fill it with your NewRandomPosition() contentHouseOne.Count times

foreach (string buildingPart in contentHouseOne)
{
    int positionIndex = random.Next(emptyCells.Count);
    Vector2 newPosition = emptyCells[positionIndex];
    emptyCells.RemoveAt(positionIndex);

    // do yout stuff using newPosition here
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! If I'm using occupiedPositons[i, j] = true; Do I have to set all grids position to false in a loop first?

Comment: C# should do this automatically, but try it out, i can't say for sure.